# Is there still no websocket support for Livecode

Tags: livecode

I am about to start a client project and Id love to do it in Livecode but the server uses websockets.

Is there a websocket client solution yet for Livecode?  My initial googling seems to have turned nothing up.

Comment: Please post this as well to the LiveCode forum:

http://forums.livecode.com

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote pure livecode implementation for myself.  At some point Il lclean it up and release it.

Comment: Once again searching if anyone has made any progress with web sockets for livecode.

I must have previously missed this message.  Jeff are you open to talking about your implementation? Does it work? I would like to do business with you.  Please email me at tom at makeshyft dot com.